# How to access the TextField From a BeanFieldGroup?

Tags: vaadin7

how can I set the BeanFieldGroup value to TextField that is created within the following statement:

```
private TextField name  = new TextField("Name");
BeanFieldGroup<MyBean> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<MyBean>(MyBean.class);
BeanFieldGroup<MyBean> fieldGroup = new BeanFieldGroup<MyBean>(MyBean.class);


fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(new MyBean());
fieldGroup.bindMemberFields(this);
layout.addComponent(TextField);
```

i try to set

```
name = (TextField) binder.getField("name");
```

but value bean value didn't get please guide

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are using two `BeanFieldGroup` Objects, binding on the first (fieldGroup) and getting the Field from the second (binder).
This works for me:

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

@Getter
@Setter
private TextField name = new TextField("Name");

@Override
public final void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    BeanFieldGroup<MyBean> fieldGroup = new BeanFieldGroup<MyBean>(MyBean.class);

    fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(new MyBean());
    fieldGroup.bindMemberFields(this);
    name = (TextField) fieldGroup.getField("name");
    layout.addComponent(name);
    setContent(layout);
}

public static class MyBean {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;
}
}
```